# Differentiate between various types of sequence diagram messages

Tags: uml, sequence-diagram

I have been using "Visual Paradigm" to model a sequence diagram and I came across various types of messages that you can use such as:

- Message
- Send Message
- Call Message
- Sequence Message

They can be either asynchronous or synchronous but there's no visual difference so, how can you tell from a diagram which type of message is it?

For example:

Apart from their semantic difference (I'm not aware of what it is) a sequence message, call message, send message, message would look like this:

[image]

I'm reading a book called "UML Distilled 3rd" and I have also looked here on [Visual Paradigm's guide](http://www.visual-paradigm.com/VPGallery/diagrams/Sequence.html) which doesn't say much about them or their usage with an example.

Answer (score 1):

- Right-click on the arrow.
- Choose Model Elements Properties
- Choose Asynchronous

You'll see as the arrow changes - synchronous ones have filled triangle arrowhead, asynchronous ones have simple two-lines arrowhead.

- Call message has () if it is with parameters.
- Return message has slashed line

All these types of messages have no notations because they are not set in the UML standard. They are local inventions of tools authors. You can set such stereotypes, too.

UML has `Synch`/`async`, `reply` (`return` in VP UML), `found`, `lost` messages, and `GeneralOrdering` connection. That is all. Read that last 2.5 standard more. It is more understandable now. Yes, it is not readable as a normal book, but it is true.